# Keyboard doesn't persist when focusing next on Text Inputs that live in separate child components

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

**The Problem**

I have text inputs that live in separate components because my app is data driven. A parent holds an array of information, passes it down to the child and the child component builds the  components. When trying to implement a 'Next' Button to focus on the next Text Input, the keyboard begins the hide animation and then pops back up.

**What I've Tried**

I've seen the facebook documentation of using `blurOnSubmit={false}` however that doesn't seem to work when the text inputs live in separate components.

**Potential Solutions**

Maybe set up a debounce that will stall the hide animation but I'm not sure where or how to go about that in the native modules

**Some Code**

This is generally what I'm doing:

```
Object.keys(objectOfInputs).map((input, index) => {
  return <ChildComponent input={input} />;
}
```

My child component has each row with a text input now:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.focusedInput === nextProps.optionId) {
      this.textInput.focus();
    }

    if (nextProps.focusedInput === null) {
      this.textInput.blur();
    }
  }

  render() {
    <View>
       <TextInput 
          showNextButton // I added this via a github solution from facebook
          keyboardType={'number-pad'}
          style={styles.someStyles}
          onChangeText={userInput => updateStateWithInput(userInput)}
          value={inputValue}
          onFocus={event => this.handleFocus(ReactNative.findNodeHandle(event.target))}
          onSubmitEditing={() => focusNext(optionId)}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
      />
    </View>
  }
}
```

This component currently sets the state to the focused input, passes that down to the children so that the child knows if it's supposed to focus.

```
class CalculatorSectionContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        focusedInput: null,
        options: Object.keys(this.props.sectionInfo.options).filter((option) => {
          return this.props.sectionInfo.options[option].type === 'input';
        }),
      };

      this.focusNext = this.focusNext.bind(this);
      this.focusCurrent = this.focusCurrent.bind(this);
  }

  focusNext(optionId) {
    this.state.options.every((option, index) => {
      if (option === optionId) {
        if (!this.state.options[index + 1]) {
          return false;
        }

        this.setState({
          focusedInput: this.state.options[index + 1],
        });

        return false;
      }

      this.setState({
        focusedInput: null,
      });

      return true;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to React Native 0.40. It will persist keyboard when changing focus to other `TextInput`

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/552c60192172f6ec503181c060c08bbc5cbcc5a4